# OLD krb5-appl packages

Tags: 18.04, source-packages, kerberos

All.

**Question:**

Do you know where to find package (or substitute package) on ubuntu 18? below:

- [krb5-clients : Precise (12.04) : Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+package/krb5-clients)
- [krb5-ftpd : Precise (12.04) : Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+package/krb5-ftpd)
- [krb5-rsh-server : Precise (12.04) : Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+package/krb5-rsh-server)
- [krb5-telnetd : Precise (12.04) : Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+package/krb5-telnetd)

**Background:**

I replace old ubuntu system to ubuntu 18.

Older systems used the above packages.

but these package was removed on ubuntu 18.

Comment: Ubuntu 18?  so you need snaps? (*yy* releases are snap based; *yy.mm* refer to traditional deb based desktop/server releases)

Comment: Hi. I am looking for a package made for ubuntu 18. snapshot... In the case of deb alone, it seems to be having a hard time resolving dependencies ...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late response, but I figured I'd leave my solution here incase someone else needs help with this very specific issue.

There's a github repo that contains all the files from the old krb5-appl packages: https://github.com/krb5/krb5-appl

Clone that repo, and run `sh autogen.sh` to generate the configure file, then run `./configure` (more documentation can be found if you look for krb5 build instructions). Now you have your make files, and simply run `make` followed by `sudo make install`